# Error while modifying mallocated string in a C struct with asm function

Tags: assembly, struct, x86-64, nasm

i would like to modify a string inside a C structure with an asm function but it is not working properly...

Let say that i have this type of structure on a 64 bits architecture :

```
typedef struct my_struct
{
    char letter1;
    char letter2;
    char *string;
}my_struct;
```

Because of the structure padding, sizeof(my_struct) should be **16** because :

```
typedef struct my_struct
{
    char letter1; // 1 byte
    char letter2; // 1 byte
    //6 bytes of padding
    char *string; // 8 bytes
}my_struct;
```

so, if i call this asm function :

```
void string_change(my_struct *s);
```

i could change for example the first letter of the struct string with :

```
mov byte [rdi+8],'x'
```

but it is not working... could you help me ?
Thanks a lot.

Here is my C code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct my_struct
{
    char letter1;
    char letter2;
    char *string;
}my_struct;

void string_change(my_struct *s);

int main(void)
{
    my_struct s;
    s.string = malloc(sizeof(char)*8);
    strcpy(s.string,"bonjour");
    printf("before call : s.string = %s\n",s.string);
    string_change(&s);
    printf("after call : s.string = %s\n",s.string);
    free(s.string);
    return 0;
}
```

and here is my assembly code :

```
bits 64
global string_change
section .text

string_change:
    mov byte [rdi+8],'x';
    ret
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  Your current code is missing too many parts to understand what went wrong.  Though one obvious problem is that you forgot one level of dereference: you are overwriting the point, not the first character of the string it points to.

Comment: Also please never say “it is not working.”  That is not an error description and is completely useless for diagnosing your program.  Instead say what you expect to happen and what happens instead.

Comment: `[rdi,8]` is an obvious syntax error, I guess you mean `[rdi+8]`, but that would still just store an `'x'` over the first byte of the pointer.  (You're correct about the struct layout).  Look at compiler output for an equivalent C function to see it load and then deref the pointer.  Or edit your question to have a [mcve] of what you *actually* did, and what the results were, and what you say with GDB.

Comment: Thanks for these answers. I've got a **free(): invalid pointer** and a **Aborted (core dumped)** error, i will look at the compiler output

Comment: @PeterCordes NASM seems to have limited(?) support for using a comma in a memory operand (https://godbolt.org/z/Ejf474na1).

Comment: @xiver77: Oh interesting, like AT&T style where you specify the base, idx, and scale separately?  It rejects `[rdi,8]` with `invalid mib expression`.  Ah, the manual (https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.3) explains:  *This is mainly intended for mib operands as used by MPX instructions, but can be used for any memory reference*.  You split the idx*scale separately from the base+disp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To follow up on Peter Cordes comment:

```
string_change:                         ;rdi = ptr to structure
        mov     rdi,[rdi+8]            ;rdi = ptr to string
        mov     byte [rdi],'x'         ;change first character of string
        ret
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really need to learn more about deferencing pointers...